# INSTR() Returning Same Value For Different Occurrences

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column storing all responses to a series of questions, all within the single column `responses`. I *cannot* adjust this column into separate columns nor adjust how this column is being stored, only manipulate the column in my query. Here is a CTE with example data and the query I'm trying to use to determine the start of each question:

```
with t as (
select 'Do you have a cell phone with data plan: No
Do you have a cell phone with wifi capability: No
Do you have home internet access: Yes
Do you have public internet access: No' responses
from dual

union all

select 'Do you have a cell phone with data plan: Yes
Do you have a cell phone with wifi capability: Yes
Do you have home internet access: Yes
Do you have public internet access: Yes'
from dual
)
select instr(responses, 'Do', 1) o1
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 2) o2
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 3) o3
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 4) o4
from t
```

Results:

| o1 | o2 | o3 | o4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 45 | 45 |
| 1 | 46 | 46 | 46 |

When running this query, I can correctly get the first and second occurrence of `'Do'` via `instr`, but occurrences 3 and 4 both return the same value as occurrence 2. My assumption is that I'm using `instr` incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to correctly format this to get occurrences 3 and 4.

Comment: You might ask another question on how to do what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter is "position" from which to search, not occurrence.
see here -
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

You sql can be modified to -

```
select instr(responses, 'Do', 1, 1) o1
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 1, 2) o2
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 1, 3) o3
    , instr(responses, 'Do', 1, 4) o4
from t
```